# How to change the super class dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

i want to change the super class dynamically in my application. the sample code is

```
public class sample extends SkinnableContainer
{
//Some Tasks
}
```

but i want to change the super class "SkinnableContainer" to "HGroup" on some occasions.

please tell me the way of achieving this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in ActionScript. I suppose you should take a look at [design patterns](http://www.oodesign.com/) which can help you to solve architectural problems (I believe your request was caused by some architectural problem).